# WordPress URL htaccess rewrite problems

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I'm having an issue after moving to a new server where my WordPress htaccess URL rewrites are redirecting ALL links back to the homepage.

Here is my current htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

On the old server I used this htaccess file with zero problems - however the new server I have the problem where ANY URL is redirecting to homepage. If I type the "unwritten" URL in (with the query strings) the page comes up fine.

Comment: Did you setup and enable permalinks in your wordpress installation `wp-admin/options-permalink.php`? Did you select a permalink option?

Comment: Yes - the permalinks option is enabled and configured properly.

Comment: So the redirect apparently works but the blog does not recognize the query vars (URL structure).

Comment: @user630270 If you disable(comment out)/remove these rules -- does it still show you the home page? (I'm thinking -- maybe redirect does not actually work and it is something else).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ideas:

1. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/all-permalinks-redirect-to-homepage-1

Deactivate all plugins an reactivate one by one.

1. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/blog-posts-redirecting-to-home-page

Click the save button in the permalinks panel.